# Why is neither the executable nor its launcher script found despite being added to PATH

Tags: python, windows, command-line, texmaker, pygmentize

I followed the instruction to install `pygmentize` in order to use syntax highlight in Latex environment, however TexMaker always produces an error says `pygmentize` is not found. I then tested to run the .cmd file itself using command prompt and the system says:

```
C:\Python27\Scripts>pygmentize.cmd
C:\Python27\python.exe: can't open file 'C:\Python27\Scripts\pygmentize': [Errno
 2] No such file or directory
```

I added path variable for both directories: `C:\Python27` and `C:\Python27\Scripts`. Within `C:\Python27\Scripts`, there are two files:

1. pygmentize.exe
2. pygmentize.cmd

Where the content of `pygmentize.cmd` is as follows:

```
@echo off
set PYTHONPATH=C:\Python27
%PYTHONPATH%\python.exe %PYTHONPATH%\Scripts\pygmentize %*
```

The original instruction doesn't contain a `\` after `%PYTHONPATH%`, I added because the I realize the error message is kinda odd when it says `C:\Python27Scripts\python.exe`.
So my question is, why doesn't the Tex system recognize the executable `pygmentize`? Following an instruction from a SO from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23458/how-to-install-syntax-highlight-package-minted-on-windows-7, I added a line:

```
\newcommand\TestAppExists[3]{#2}
```

in my .tex file and it worked only under Ubuntu. So what's the purpose of the .cmd file in this case?

Comment: Do you in fact have a file called `C:\Python27\Scripts\Scripts\pygmentize`?

Comment: @Sorpigal: No, there is no file named `pygmentize`. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cmd.exe` will prefer .exe to .cmd when choosing which `pygmentize` to execute, all else begin equal. `python.exe` will perform no magic at all and will not know what to make of `C:\Python27\Scripts\pygmentize` unless a file with that exact name exists.

Comment: @Chan: Do you know what this is supposed to be doing? I don't. I suspect that the example Windows Command script is broken: The file passed to `python.exe` should be a python script, I would think.

Comment: I really don't know, but I got it fixed by re-installing the package. My guess was that the cmd file give an instructions to Windows to find the `pygmentize.exe`. Once again, thanks a lot.